# how to disable prints in tensorflow2?

Tags: keras, sequential, tensorflow2.x

I'm using TF2 with python3, I want to disable the TensorFlow prints of the epoch progress.
I know I can disable the log by writing verbose = 0, but then I want to see the prints at all. I would like to see only the results of each epoch and not the progress inside it.

> epoch_hist = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=100,
>   batch_size=32, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),verbose=0,
>   callbacks=[early_stopping_callback])

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need `verbose=2`

it permits you to see only the results of each epoch and not the progress inside it